# Remove place names from the layout in the print composer using a WMS

Tags: wms, text, remove

I am new to working with maps and I am going to make a map presenting the study sites in my theisis.

As a map I am using a WMS-map provided by geonorge.no. I am wondering if there is a function in the QGI so I can remove the unwanted names that is showing up when I am zooming into the map?  As I am zooming in lots of names are showing up. This is unwanted for an illustration in my theisis.

[image: As you can see no names are showing up when I am zooming out.]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what layers are available at particular WMS service. Since you didn't specify which specific service you are using, it's impossible to give definitive answer. But generally you start with the `GetCapabilities` request to your WMS service and check what layers are available.

For example, for one of `geonorge.no` WMTS services request would be (gkt key is valid only for today):

```
https://gatekeeper2.geonorge.no/BaatGatekeeper/gk/gk.cache_wmts?&Service=WMTS&Request=GetCapabilities&gkt=B31A0E335595438DC80B159DC182E51CB1639869E2139CF72A54890E44C94F77A360714FB058C7A57701B96D70DD1EC0E525F7991843B8A08D018F0853CD0DA1
```

In the result you go through layers (there are tens of them) and try those that seem promising (name looks like `<ows:Identifier>layer_name</ows:Identifier>`). I tried a few and found one, that might be good for your purposes. Name of the layer is `terreng_norgeskart` and it looks like this:

[image]